# Would you presume that a "sixth sense" be considered foresight or intuition?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

thefreedictionary for idioms suggests:

**sixth sense**:
*a supposed power to know or feel things that are not perceptible by the five senses of sight, hearing, smell, taste, and touch*.

*"My sixth sense told me to avoid going home by my usual route. Later I discovered there had been a fatal accident on it. Jane's sixth sense demanded that she not trust Tom, even though he seemed honest enough."*

Given that understanding and definition, including my knowledge on it, I would personally presume so.

What are the facts?

Comment: The way you've currently phrased your question, it is very likely to be closed as Primarily Opinion-Based. StackExchange strives to provide objective, authoritative answers, so inviting “what do you think about this?” answers is almost certainly going to get it closed. Your question would do a lot better if you rephrased it to ask instead for any authoritative sources that may be able to tell us whether the notion of foresight or intuition is inherently present in the concept of ‘sixth sense’ generally (or similar).

Comment: Logically, the sixth sense could only be manifest to the rest of us in the future. If we could sense it now, it wouldn't be a sixth sense, would it? So we have to wait for some effect to take place which we can sense. It appears to us as though the other anticipated the event rather than sensed some precursor to it.

Comment: Also, please ask your question *in the body of your question*. Imagine a book with its cover torn off.  Most real books would still make sense if you didn’t know their titles.  Your question doesn’t make sense without its title.

Answer (score 0):

A sixth sense is specifically another sense on top of the main 5, which would be more metaphysical in nature. Intuition is more or less a gut feeling like, "I had a feeling something was wrong." In my opinion a sixth sense would be able gather more data than just a "feeling." A sixth sense would tap into more details about a person for instance knowing what their mother looks like.

But that's just my opinion, I would say they are both psychically related though.

Comment: Sometimes intuition is referred to metaphorically as a sixth sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to try [another dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sixth-sense):

> any supposed sense or means of perception, **such as intuition or clairvoyance**, other than the five senses of sight, hearing, touch, taste, and smell

*(emphasis mine)*

I'm struggling to think of uses of "sixth sense" other than intuition and foresight/clairvoyance (note that foresight and intuition are different things). The only example I came up with was from the movie The Sixth Sense, in which a kid could **see and hear dead people**.

So, I would agree that you can normally interpret "sixth sense" to mean "intuition or foresight".